# Jquery not working at all but other Javascript code runs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm facing a problem with my jquery. I have a table with multiple records and with each record there is delete link. On clicking that link that particular record is deleted. That is fine but what I am trying for is when a record is deleted it simply disappears without any page refresh. For that I have a jquery code which works fine on a stand alone page but when I'm trying to integrate it with my actual code nothing happens at all. I replaced $ with jQuery but still nothing happening. I also checked for other causes but nothing worked. Can someone point out what could possibly be missing or I'm doing wrong. Codes are below:

This is my row code which is inside a foreach so multiple ones are created

```
<tr class="showdel">
   <td class="align"><input type="checkbox" name="instanceids[]" id="checkid" value="<?php echo $instanceid; ?>" /></td>
   <td class="align"><?php echo $i++.'.'; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
   <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="delete" id="<?php echo $instanceid; ?>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

Below is my jquery code which deletes the record and it simply disappears. It is in head section of the page.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function()
        {
            jQuery(".delete").click(function()
            {
                var element = jQuery(this);
                var del_id = element.attr("id");
                var info = 'id=' + del_id;
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
                {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "content_list.php",
                        data: info,
                        success: function() {}
                    });

                    jQuery(this).parents(".showdel").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
                    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Please point out what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

PS: Here is my whole head section. See if this helps. May be ordering of scripts is wrong.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title><?php echo $client; ?> Admin</title>
    <!-- bootstrap core css -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- custom css -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- style.css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- paginng css -->
    <link href="css/pagination.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".delete").click(function()
    {
        var element = jQuery(this);
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "content_list.php",
                data: info,
                success: function() {}
            });

            jQuery(this).parents(".show").animate({ backgroundColor: "#003" }, "slow")
            .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
        }
        return false;
    });
    </script>

    <!-- form validation scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_category.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_subcategory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_subsubcategory.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectall.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_content.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate_data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax_scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also my table is loaded by ajax call as Alpesh Panchal below pointed out.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Debug your code: put some console.log calls at different levels to see if the script is executed, the outer-most function is executed, etc. Come back with the results.

Comment: did you try `jQuery(".delete").on('click', function() {` instead of `click`

Comment: @Muhammad Atif:- No errors, no warning. It is not responding at all. I tried adding an alert box but still no response.

Comment: try by removing  jQuery(function() and give the click function only

Comment: Where did you put the alert? Please be very specific on what you tried. Put it at all levels. Outside the outermost function, alert the jQuery object (better use console for this, not alert). Make sure you include jQuery lib before the code itself, and that all other code and script tags come after it.

Comment: @trincot: I placed alert boxes at each step after every opening curly brace.

Comment: @Sundar:- There is no value of $ or jQuery. Nothing is happening on click.

Comment: Are you trying to select your .delete class before it exists?  In the original function you posted it is being called after the document has been loaded, but not in the code you put up of your full head element

Answer (score 1):

Since your data table is loading by an ajax call, your selection of `jQuery(".delete")` is actually empty when it is trying to set the event handlers before the data is loaded. So, the solution is to set the event handler to the `document` itself and set a filter for your `.delete` element. Like this :

```
jQuery(document).on('click',".delete",(function()
{
  //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to check any javascript error using firebug console during page loading. Sometimes javascript errors prevents rest of javascript to execute.
2. Make sure that your table is not being loading by ajax call. If it is then jQuery's click event won't be binded to it. To bind it, you need to use ajaxStop() event handler to bind delete function.
3. If ajaxStop() doesn't work then you can create your delete click function separately and call it on "onclick" event of link

e.g.

```
<td>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return delete_function();" class="delete" id="<?php echo $instanceid; ?>">Delete</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the jQuery `.animate()` method only numeric values can be animated (like "margin:30px"). String values cannot be animated (like "background-color:red").

[Read more in jQuery docs.](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Instead of `animate` use the `.css()` method of jQuery to change color and/or hide elements.